# TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable in django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to return the the string given in URL but I am getting this error `TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable` don't know how to rectify this.

URL I am passing - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict/?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O`

my `views.py` file

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.data.get('solute',None)
    solvent = request.data.get('solvent',None)
    results = [solute,solvent]
    return Response({'result':result}, status=200)
```

```
Update: after correcting `result` to `results` it solved my problem
```

But it is returning an `null` response in the output rather than getting `CC(C)(C)Br` and `CC(C)(C)O` which are my inputs through URL

[image]

Comment: It seems a typo. you missed a `s` letter in last line:  `{'result':results}`  not `{'result':result}`. Choose better names for your functions and variables to avoid these problems.

Comment: Thanks but after correcting i am getting null as the output but I should get what I have given in the URL right? @MojtabaKamyabi

Comment: @harsh request.data works for 'POST', 'PUT' and 'PATCH' methods according to DRF documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/). Why not use dynamic url for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be passing the function `result` itself to `Response`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ended up passing your view function itself as a value in the context dictionary which may not have been your intention. You may want to get things corrected this way:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.data.get('solute',None)
    solvent = request.data.get('solvent',None)
    results = [solute,solvent]
    return Response({'result':results}, status=200)
```

Note that the name of your view function is `result` and the value you intend store in the context dictionary is `results`

> UPDATE

Regarding your update, you can get it done this way:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def predict(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = request.GET
        return Response({'result':list(results.values())},status=200)
```

the`request.data` method works for post, put, and, patch method while the `request.GET` method returns a dictionary of all URL query parameters